# How to access dynamic variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, sfml

```
class dynamic
{      
public:        
    dynamic();
    void value();
    void move();
    sf::RectangleShape rs;           
};

dynamic::dynamic()    
{
    rs.setSize(sf::Vector2f(200,200));
    rs.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    rs.setPosition(300, 300)   
};

void dynamic::move()
{
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
    {            
        spr.move(0, 1);           
        value();            
    }
}

void dynamic::value()
{
    return spr.getposition.y
}
```

---------------- Diffrent Class ---------------

```
class context : public dynamic {

public:
    void valueWrite();

};

void context::valueWrite(){        

    std::cout << spr.getposition.y;

}
```

---------------- Game Class ---------------

```
class Game {
public:        
    Game();

    void draw();        
    void update();
    void loop();        

    sf::RenderWindow window;

    context m_context;
    dynamic m_dynamic;        
};


game::game(): window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window")    
{

}

void game::loop()
{
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        update();
        draw();

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {                    
                window.close();
            }
        }
    }
}

void game::draw()
{
    window.clear();
    m_dynamic.render(window);
    window.display();
}

void game::update()    
{
    m_dynamic.move();
    m_context.valueWrite();        
}
```

When I run this program of main, my spr position evertime same.
Console = 300 300 300 300 300.........

I want to write the current value of the class context

How to fix this problem.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking.  Do you expect `m_context` and `m_dynamic` to share the same state?

Comment: Yes kind of,when i pressed the down key spr position change. But valueWrite function everytime same. İ want to change this position function valuewrite. Sorry my bad english.i hope you understand me

Answer (score 0):

In this code m_dynamic and m_context objects independent from each other. The value that m_context try to write is not m_dynamic's value.

You should create just a "context" object. And you will call "move" function from "context" object.

```
m_context.move();
m_context.valueWrite();
```

and render too.

Comment: As I can see, you have problems with inheritance logic. You may want to take a look this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm